# yup validation for array of values

Tags: yup

I'm trying to validate array for not having duplicate items in different select field. But my .test function doesn't work. Can I write validation in such format?

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  myArray: Yup.array()
    .of(
      Yup.object().shape({
        id: Yup.string().required('Select ID'),
      })
    )
    .test('is-unique', 'Duplicate selected', function (value) {
      // logic
      // return true / false
    })
})
```

I tried just return true or false inside .test but I still doesn't see 'Duplicate selected' error.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with your schema. Your schema works (provided your "logic" is correct): https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitest-dev-vitest-gb3ejj?file=package.json,src%2Fbasic.ts,test%2Fbasic.test.ts&initialPath=__vitest__/ Show us how you are using your schema, include your logic as well.

Comment: the issue is my schema doesnt return 'Duplicate selected' even if I return false...
I have few Select components and I want to validate that they don't have duplicates. Logic for validation is simple, I can handle it. But somewhere is an error with yup

Comment: There's not an error with yup, it's well documented and well used. As you've seen in my stackblitz, the schema works fine. There's likely an error in how **you're using yup to retrieve the error message**. Can you show the rest of your code?